# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: messages

Tags: php, laravel

estou tentando exibir todas os registros de uma tabela mas apresenta o seguinte erro: Undefined variable: messages (View: /Users/henrique/Documents/Laravel Projects/blog/resources/views/messages.blade.php)

meu controller:

```
public function getMessages() {
    $messages = \App\Message::all();

    return view('messages')->with(['Messages' => $messages]);
    //return view('messages',[ 'images' => $messages]);
}
```

minha view:

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('content')

    <h1>Messages</h1>

    @if(count($messages)>0)
        @foreach($messages as $message)
            <ul>
                <li class="list-group-item">Name: {{$message->name}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Email: {{$message->email}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Message: {{$message->message}}</li>
            </ul>

        @endforeach

    @endif

@endsection

@section('sidebar')

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No controller está 'Messages' com letra maiúscula!
E na view tenta pegar a variável com letra minúscula no @foreach.

Modifique no controller para:

```
return view('messages')->with(['messages' => $messages]);
```

Podes fazer assim tmb.

```
return view('messages')->withMessages($messages);
```

Ou:

```
return view('messages', compact('messages'));
```